# R plotting 2 densities on the same graph

Tags: r, math, graph

Have been asked how to do the following question, this is homework to let you know but just looking for a confirmation, no answers as such.

Edits appreciated as I am not sure how to use it still.

Plot in the same figure the densities of N(µ = 1, σ2 = 1) and N(µ =
−3.5, σ2 = 3/4)

```
ms<-rnorm(50)
rnorm(10,5,2)
pnorm(0)
qnorm(0.05)

hist(ms, prob=TRUE)
mu<-mean(ms)
sig<-sd(ms)

x<-seq(-4,4, length=1000)
y<-dnorm(x,mu,sig)
lines(x,y)
```

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDgoM.png)

Comment: try  `plot(function(x) dnorm(x,1), xlim=c(-6,4))`  when you try to put the other part on look at `add=TRUE argument to plot.

Comment: Check out `?curve` as in `curve(dnorm(x,1,1),-3,5)` - `add = TRUE` applies here too