# Plot two densities in the same figure in R

Tags: r, plot, graph

I have two densities 
`N(µ = 1, σ2 = 1)` and 
`N(µ = −3.5, σ2 = 3/4).` I know I am have to use `plot()` and `lines()` but I am not sure how to convert the densities into functions. I am not even sure if that's what I have to do.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You have two times two _moments_, i.e. the first raw moment is your mean, $\mu$, and the second central moment is the variance, $\sigma$. You can use that information to [plot a function](http://www.statisticsblog.com/tag/density-functions/) or you could [generate some data](https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/probability.html) that you could plot, more or less with the same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R plotting 2 densities on the same graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649588/r-plotting-2-densities-on-the-same-graph)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `dnorm()` function, along with a sequence of numbers generated with `seq()` to get values to plot a pdf:

Get 5000 values between -10 and 10

```
x<-seq(-10,10,length=5000)
```

Calculate values - notice that `dnorm()` uses standard deviation and not the variance, so you need to take the square root of 0.75.

```
y<-dnorm(x,mean=0, sd=1)
z<-dnorm(x, mean = -3.5, sd = sqrt(0.75))
```

Plot first density in red with `plot()`:

```
plot(x, y, type="l" , ylim = c(0,1), xlim = c(-8,8), col = "red")
```

Plot second one on top of first using the `lines()` function in blue:

```
lines(x,z, type = "l", col = "blue")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code will plot you two densities in the same figure ;)

```
library(tidyverse)

seq(-10, 10, by = 0.1) %>% 
  tibble(x = .) %>% 
  mutate(D1 = dnorm(x, 1, 1),
         D2 = dnorm(x, -3.5, 3/4)) %>% 
  gather(-x, key = Distribution, value = Value) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, Value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = Distribution))
```

[image]